# Puppet resource ordering with puppet module "maestrodev/puppet-wget"?

Tags: ruby, puppet

Puppet allows [resource ordering](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/ordering.html) to specify the order in which resources are installed/created.

My ruby script uses `package` to install an application.

```
$app_firefox_name = "Firefox-0-DL"
$app_firefoxt_dmg = "/tmp/$app_firefox_name.dmg"

package { $app_firefoxt_app:
     ensure => installed,
     provider => appdmg,
 source => $app_firefoxt_dmg,
     require => wget::fetch[$app_firefoxt_app],
 }
```

Prior installation, the script requires to download the application. The script uses puppet module `https://github.com/maestrodev/puppet-wget` to fetch the application.

```
wget::fetch { $app_firefox_name:
    source      => "http://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-21.0&os=osx&lang=en-GB",
    destination => $app_firefox_dmg,
    timeout     => 0,
    verbose     => true
}
```

I don't know if maestrodev/puppet-wget module defines a type.

**Does the following code define a type that can be used to describe resource ordering (as defined in the Puppet's resource ordering document) ?**

```
define wget::fetch (
  $source,
  $destination,
  $timeout            = '0',
  $verbose            = false,
  $redownload         = false,
  $nocheckcertificate = false,
  $execuser           = 'root',
) { ... }
```

If yes, **how can I use puppet's before metaparameter to express the relationship download app -> install app package ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I workaround the issue using Puppet's `package` resource to download the application.

```
package { $app_firefoxt_app:
 ensure => installed,
 provider => appdmg,
 source => "http://download.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/latest/mac/en-GB/Firefox%2021.0.dmg"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing the point of your question, but if the require is not working, try capitalising it:

```
require => Wget::Fetch[$app_firefoxt_app]
```